# In RcppAlgos, is there documentation for checking if an iterator is false?

Tags: r, iterator

[This vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppAlgos/vignettes/CombinatoricsIterators.html) shows a way to loop over an iterator from `RcppAlgos` until it has no iterations left. Here are the relevant parts:

```
## Initialize the iterator
a = comboIter(5, 3)

a$nextIter()
iter = a$currIter()

## Iterate until there are no more
while (!isFALSE(iter)) {
    cat(i, " ", iter, "\n")
    iter = a$nextIter()
    i = i + 1
}
```

The `while (!isFALSE(iter))` line is what has my interest. I've been looking over [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppAlgos/RcppAlgos.pdf#Rfn.comboIter.1) for `comboIter` and I can't see anywhere that indicates that `comboIter` can take a true or false value. Clearly, it can and it does when the iterator object has ran out of iterations, but **where is this documented**?

Comment: As the author of this package, my intent was to mimic `std::next_permutation` and others from the STL as best as I could. When an iterator is finished, it simply returns `FALSE`. What is different than the STL implementations is that it doesn't return `TRUE` when the next iteration isn't the last one, rather it simply returns the next combination. That is why the example makes use of the base R function `isFALSE`. The behavior of `isFALSE` is to return `TRUE` only when the value being evaluated is the logical value `FALSE` and to return `FALSE` otherwise.

Comment: To answer "Where is this documented?"... I scoured all of the many resources thinking that _"of course, I documented this..."_ only to come up with nothing. I will be sure to include this in the next release.

Comment: Lastly, this has nothing to do with `Rcpp` per se, just something overlooked by an author of a package that utilizes `Rcpp`.

Comment: @JosephWood Well, that's it settled! Great package by the way.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and I welcome it. While this question is okay for stack overflow, it is probably better to file an issue with the maintainer like so: https://github.com/jwood000/RcppAlgos/issues/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, this is [a know issue that is yet to be fixed](https://github.com/jwood000/RcppAlgos/issues/15). For the time being, the answer is "they don't".